# Django, filter query set through multiple entry_set.all() relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Server(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Schedule(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class LineItem(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I have some really nasty logic in my template to display any LineItems that relate to a given Server object in a server detail page

```
{% for schedule in server.client.schedule_set.all %}
    {% for lineitem in schedule.lineitem_set.all %}
        {% if lineitem.server == server %}
            {{ lineitem.id }}
            {{ lineitem.description }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE: For Clarification**

I'm able to obtain the relevant information from inside by view with the following:

```
def serverDetailView(request, pk):
    # Fetches all the line items related to the current server
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)
    line_items = []
    for schedule in server.client.schedule_set.all():
        items = schedule.lineitem_set.all()
        for item in items:
            if item.server == server:
                line_items.append(item)
    context = {'server': server, 'line_items': line_items}
    return render(request, 'reports/server_detail.html', context)
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for item in line_items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

The question is, can I filter down these relevant LineItems with a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than following the reverse relationship `model_set` managers. You can follow the `ForeignKey` relationships by using the double underscore notation from the Django ORM

```
line_items = LineItem.objects.filter(schedule__client=server.client)
```

Comment: It never actually occurred to me to do this way round! I'm off work until tomorrow I'm 99% this will be what I'm after. Thanks!